# Jquery submit and live show

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery submit problem. The problem is after submit the data didn't show automatically. So I must click refresh.

And this is my code so far :

PHP function to show the data

```
function formatTweet($message,$date_post,$profile_pic,$full_name)
{
if(is_string($date_post)) $date_post=strtotime($date_post);

$message=htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($message));

return'
<td>
<a href="#"><img src="'.$profile_pic.'"/></a>
<div class="tweetTxt">
<div class="profile_name">'.$full_name.'</div>
<div class="haps_post">'.$message.'</div>
<div class="post_time">'.relativeTime($date_post).'</div>
</div>
</td>
<tr>';
}
```

PHP Function to save the data

```
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
require ("functions.php");
require ("config.php");

if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST['inputField']=stripslashes($_POST['inputField']);
$_POST['username']=stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$date_post = date("Y-m-d G:i");

$_POST['inputField'] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['inputField']),$link);

$_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']),$link);

if(mb_strlen($_POST['inputField']) < 1 || mb_strlen($_POST['inputField'])>140)
die("0");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages SET message='".$_POST['inputField']."',username='".$_POST['username']."',date_post='$date_post'");

if(mysql_affected_rows($link)!=1)
die("0");

echo formatTweet($_POST['inputField'],$date_post,$_POST['username'],time());
```

Someone have an idea / suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: from a quick glance: You're only saving the data source. You must also edit it on the page that is running =)